# Error bar doesn't scale according to y axis

Tags: bar-chart, tikzscale, error-bars

I was building a graph with error bars for my thesis. However the values for error bars don't seem to scale according to the y axis and so the size is completely off. I'm not experienced with LaTeX, so if anyone could help i'd be very grateful.

My MWE:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
    height = 8cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=19pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel = {\% of null tokens},
    symbolic x coords={Subject,Object,Copula},
    xtick = data,
    ytick={0.00, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1},
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
            at={(0.97,0.95)},
            anchor=north east,
            column sep=1ex
    }
]
    \addplot+[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit]
        coordinates {
        (Subject, 0.318) +- (0.3035, 0.3322)
        (Object, 0.238) +- (0.2051, 0.2748)
        (Copula, 0.12) +- (0.09, 0.14)
        };

    \addplot+[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit]
         coordinates {
         (Subject, 0.315) +- (0.2837, 0.3485)
         (Object, 0.130) +- (0.0854, 0.1878)
         (Copula, 0.084) +- (0.0511, 0.1276)
         };
    \legend{Gen 1, Gen 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! After completing your document to a minimal working example, adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` and replacing `ybar=2*\pgflinewidth` with `ybar=\pgflinewidth` for better accuracy, the error bars look quite correct. Of course, this assumes the error values you provided are *absolute* error values, since you have used `y explicit`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
    height = 8cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar=\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=19pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel = {\% of null tokens},
    symbolic x coords={Subject, Object, Copula},
    xtick = data,
    ytick={0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1},
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
            at={(0.97,0.95)},
            anchor=north east,
    }
]
    \addplot+[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        coordinates {
        (Subject, 0.318) +- (0.3035, 0.3322)
        (Object, 0.238) +- (0.2051, 0.2748)
        (Copula, 0.12) +- (0.09, 0.14)
        };

    \addplot+[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
         coordinates {
         (Subject, 0.315) +- (0.2837, 0.3485)
         (Object, 0.130) +- (0.0854, 0.1878)
         (Copula, 0.084) +- (0.0511, 0.1276)
         };
    \legend{Gen 1, Gen 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the error values to be interpreted as *relative* ones, use `y explicit relative` instead of `y explicit`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
    height = 8cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar=\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=19pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel = {\% of null tokens},
    symbolic x coords={Subject, Object, Copula},
    xtick = data,
    ytick={0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1},
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
            at={(0.97,0.95)},
            anchor=north east,
    }
]
    \addplot+[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit relative]
        coordinates {
        (Subject, 0.318) +- (0.3035, 0.3322)
        (Object, 0.238) +- (0.2051, 0.2748)
        (Copula, 0.12) +- (0.09, 0.14)
        };

    \addplot+[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit relative]
         coordinates {
         (Subject, 0.315) +- (0.2837, 0.3485)
         (Object, 0.130) +- (0.0854, 0.1878)
         (Copula, 0.084) +- (0.0511, 0.1276)
         };
    \legend{Gen 1, Gen 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please provide a complete example next time, one that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. The difference between y explicit and y relative is something I didn't know about, so thank you for the helpful explanation. However i still don't understand how the error bar scales down even after you've changed it to relative values. For example, the error margins for subject is between 30.35 - 33.22% (the bar value is 31.8). On the graph however, the lower limit of the error bar is only just above the 20% mark, and the upper limit is above the 40%. Am I missing something mathematical here?

Comment: Apparently, you are not computing the percentages correctly. Here, the provided 0.3035 means the absolute negative error for the first point of the first plot is at most 0.318×0.3035 = 0.096513. For the positive error (same plot and same point), it is 0.318×0.3322 = 0.1056396. So, the possible interval for the real value according to the provided relative error is [0.318 - 0.096513, 0.318 + 0.1056396], that is [0.221487, 0.4236396]. This is precisely what the leftmost blue segment (the error bar) on the first graph shows.

Comment: aha, thank you. You saved the day.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. :-)